# I can't see JSON data in ionic3 when I use phone device, (JSON data from external Url)

Tags: android, ios, json, ionic2, ionic3

I have a problem with run app in phone devices(IOS & android).
I had this problem in browsers too, and this error happend:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'my-external-url'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://'localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

but I solved that with [this solution](http://crossorigin.me/), but this solution didn't work for mobile devices

Thanks

Comment: What error exactly you are getting on Android?

Comment: I must be after adding these code in config.xml :
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
rebuild android or ios platforms whit this code:
ionic cordova run android(or IOS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these in your config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

And make sure you have [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot "Swapnil Patwa"

Answer (score 1):

Attention:
When used [Crossorigin](http://crossorigin.me) for this problem, consider that this site has 1day cache.